# simple upper-casifier loop infinitely

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, infinite-loop

simple upper-casifier loop infinitely

what's wrong with my code?

any advice?

my programming environment is linux, emacs, assembly, at&t syntax

```
.section .data
    .section .bss
    .lcomm buffer,1
    .section .text
    .global _start
_start:
    movl %esp,%ebp
    subl $8,%esp
    #8(%ebp) is 2nd arg == input
    #12(%ebp) is 3rd arg == output

    #open,read,open,write,close
    movl $5,%eax
    movl 8(%ebp),%ebx
    movl $0,%ecx
    movl $0666,%edx
    int $0x80
    #%eax contains input's fd
    #movl to first local var
    movl %eax,-4(%ebp)

    movl $5,%eax
    movl 12(%ebp),%ebx
    movl $03101,%ecx
    movl $0666,%edx
    int $0x80
    #eax contains output's fd
    #movl to second local var
    movl %eax,-8(%ebp)
loop:           
    #read 1 byte from file 1st byte of data
    movl $3,%eax
    movl -4(%ebp),%ebx
    movl $buffer,%ecx
    movl $1,%edx
    int $0x80
    #buffer contains 1 byte of file
    cmpb $0,buffer
    je program_exit

    pushl buffer
    call convert    #will return converted to %al
    addl $4,%esp
    movb %al,buffer

    #write 1 byte from buffer to file
    movl $1,%edx
    movl $buffer,%ecx
    movl -8(%ebp),%ebx
    movl $4,%eax
    int $0x80
    jmp loop
program_exit:
    movl buffer,%ebx
    movl $1,%eax
    int $0x80

    .type convert,@function
convert:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp,%ebp
    movb 8(%ebp),%al #1 byte data in the buffer 
    cmpb $'a',%al
    jl convert_end
    cmpb $'z',%al
    jg convert_end
    addb $32,%al #convert to upper

convert_end:
    movl %ebp,%esp
    popl %ebp
    ret
```

Comment: is it because there is no null character at the end of file? I made input file with mousepad and type abcdefghij. if I change exit condition 0 to 'j' it does not loop infinitely. what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `read(2)` signals an end-of-file condition by *returning* `0`. You're trying to find the end of the file by looking for an ascii `NUL`, which is very rare on Unix-derived systems. (If you want an easy way to make a terabyte-sized file, `dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/huge bs=1048576 seek=1048576 count=1`. The whole thing will be filled with ascii `NUL` characters. (Or the integer `0`, however you want to interpret it.)

You need to modify your code to find the end of file by comparing the return value of the `read(2)` system call, not by looking at the data you receive into your buffer.